# Were jprobes removed from kernel v4?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kprobe

There is a `jprobe_example.c` in [v3](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18/source/samples/kprobes). But it is missing in [v4](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.5/source/samples/kprobes). I tried to compile v3 example having kernel v4 and it works giving me `jprobe_example.ko`, but when I try to `insmod` it, it fails with

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module jprobe_example.ko: Operation not permitted.
```

`/var/log/syslog` says that `register_jprobe failed, returned -38`

Another two examples are `insmod`-ed fine. So, the question is, were jprobes removed from the kernel v4? Why can I compile the module but not `insmod` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jprobes are deprecated in the Linux kernel and the sample file was removed in commit [`9be95bd`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9be95bdc53c12ada23e39027237fd05e1393d893):

```
commit 9be95bdc53c12ada23e39027237fd05e1393d893
Author: Masami Hiramatsu <mhiramat@kernel.org>
Date:   Fri Oct 6 08:15:57 2017 +0900

    kprobes: Remove the jprobes sample code

    Remove the jprobes sample module because jprobes are deprecated.

    [...]
```

That commit was merged in 4.15-rc1.

[-38 is `-ENOSYS`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.18/source/include/linux/kprobes.h#L471), the error code for invalid system call numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Masami Hiramatsu decide to abolish jprobe APIs in this email: https://lwn.net/Articles/735667/

> Hi,
>
> This series abolishes jprobe APIs and remove or disable related
> code. This is a preparation of removing all jprobe code (including
> kprobe's break_handler.)
> I'm not so sure how many jprobe users still exists, but
> please migrate your tool to trace-event or perf-probe.
>
> As we discussed this thread ( https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/10/2/386 ),
> we decided to remove jprobe.
>
> Nowadays ftrace and other tracing features are enough matured
> to replace jprobe use-cases. Users can safely use ftrace and
> perf probe etc. for their use cases. So we have better way.
> IOW, jprobe finished its task.
>
> People who still use jprobe, must migrate to other tracing features.
> Please consider to migrate your tool to following options.

The reason I guess from the email is a bug talking about IRQs in https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/10/2/386